# problems I meet when installing deeplab:.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `Mat_CreateVer'

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, image-segmentation, conv-neural-network

DeepLab is a state-of-art deep learning system for semantic image segmentation built on top of Caffe.I followed this website to install it:https://bitbucket.org/deeplab/deeplab-public/I clone the files to /deeplab/code and use the command:`make all`
and I came across the error

`.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to`Mat_CreateVer'`

Is there someone know how to solve this?I'll appreciate it a lot!Many thanks!

---

here is the Makefile.config .I've add the matio path to this install file:

```
## Refer to http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html
# Contributions simplifying and improving our build system are welcome!

# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
# USE_CUDNN := 1

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
# CPU_ONLY := 1

# uncomment to disable IO dependencies and corresponding data layers
# USE_OPENCV := 0
# USE_LEVELDB := 0
# USE_LMDB := 0

# uncomment to allow MDB_NOLOCK when reading LMDB files (only if necessary)
#   You should not set this flag if you will be reading LMDBs with any
#   possibility of simultaneous read and write
# ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK := 1

# Uncomment if you're using OpenCV 3
# OPENCV_VERSION := 3

# To customize your choice of compiler, uncomment and set the following.
# N.B. the default for Linux is g++ and the default for OSX is clang++
# CUSTOM_CXX := g++

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
# On Ubuntu 14.04, if cuda tools are installed via
# "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" then use this instead:
# CUDA_DIR := /usr

# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50

# BLAS choice:
# atlas for ATLAS (default)
# mkl for MKL
# open for OpenBlas
BLAS := atlas
# Custom (MKL/ATLAS/OpenBLAS) include and lib directories.
# Leave commented to accept the defaults for your choice of BLAS
# (which should work)!
# BLAS_INCLUDE := /path/to/your/blas
# BLAS_LIB := /path/to/your/blas

# Homebrew puts openblas in a directory that is not on the standard search path
# BLAS_INCLUDE := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/include
# BLAS_LIB := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/lib

# This is required only if you will compile the matlab interface.
# MATLAB directory should contain the mex binary in /bin.
# MATLAB_DIR := /usr/local
# MATLAB_DIR := /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app

# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.
# ANACONDA_HOME := $(HOME)/anaconda
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
        # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
        # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include \

# Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
# PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.5m
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.5m \
#                 /usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include

# We need to be able to find libpythonX.X.so or .dylib.
PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
# PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib

# Homebrew installs numpy in a non standard path (keg only)
# PYTHON_INCLUDE += $(dir $(shell python -c 'import numpy.core; print(numpy.core.__file__)'))/include
# PYTHON_LIB += $(shell brew --prefix numpy)/lib

# Uncomment to support layers written in Python (will link against Python libs)
# WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1

# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /home/zhaimo/deeplab/matio-1.5.2/src
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /home/zhaimo/deeplab/matio-1.5.2/src/.libs


# If Homebrew is installed at a non standard location (for example your home directory) and you use it for general dependencies
# INCLUDE_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/include
# LIBRARY_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/lib

# Uncomment to use `pkg-config` to specify OpenCV library paths.
# (Usually not necessary -- OpenCV libraries are normally installed in one of the above $LIBRARY_DIRS.)
# USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1

BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute

# Uncomment for debugging. Does not work on OSX due to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/171
# DEBUG := 1

# The ID of the GPU that 'make runtest' will use to run unit tests.
TEST_GPUID := 0

# enable pretty build (comment to see full commands)
Q ?= @
```

Comment: did you install matio?

Comment: It must be a path issue then.. I think caffe is not able to find matio

Comment: I've paste the Makefile of caffe,is there anything wrong please?

Comment: can you paste both Makefile and Makefile.config?

Comment: I did not modify the Makefile,it is the same as the original file that deeplab provides.where should I modify ,please?

Comment: can you check for matio in your LDFLAGS?

Comment: many thanks for your concerning.I'm a freshman in deep-learning,Can you make the question clearer?should I add the matio path to LDFLAGS in Makefile?

Comment: `LIBRARIES += matio` add this line in your `Makefile` and clean build it.

Comment: hi,I change the file as you said,but it does not work

Comment: can you upload your Makefile?

Comment: [Makefile](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23391944/)

Comment: It was there even before you added right... must be some path issue

Comment: I am very confused about where to add the path,anyway many thanks for your help

Comment: do  you have `libmatio.so` in `/usr/local/lib` ?

Comment: yes I've checked it.